# Spring Web: How to tell if DispatcherServlet failed to load?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm wondering what the best practice is for detecting whether Spring's `DispatcherServlet` has failed to load.  I'm interested in catching all errors the servlet might have encountered while loading, but I'm most interested in errors caused by the servlet context file being incorrect (as this is the most common error).

I'm guessing I need to hook into (override) some method on `DispatcherServlet`, but I don't know what I should be hooking in to that would catch all possible errors.

I'm able to tell if the application context has failed via overriding the `ContextLoaderListener`, but I haven't been able to figure out a way to tell if the `DispatcherServlet` has failed.

Any help would be much appreciated!  Thanks!

Comment: I can't give an exact answer but, since nobody is answering...I seem to remember jboss exposing status and possibly error message via JMX. Obviously this is container-specific (and even a little vague) but maybe other containers provide something similar.

Comment: Yes, this is a little vague but I don't think it would be container specific, as the DispatcherServlet is probably going to act the same across containers.  We have many servlets in our application, with methods to detect when each one fails, so we'd just like to be able to tell when Spring's DispatcherServlet fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override [init()](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/Servlet.html#init%28javax.servlet.ServletConfig%29):

```
@Override
void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
    try {
        super.init();
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        // Do something

        throw t;
    }
}
```